# Google Places API Web Services API Key Invalid

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I just signed up for the `Google Places API`. They issued me a `server key` which I am using in my code.

Here is my code:

```
    function getLatLon($address)
    {
      $curl=curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.rawurlencode($address));
      curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      $json=curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);
      $json=json_decode($json);
      $details=[
         'lat'=>$json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat,
         'lng'=>$json->results[0]->geometry->location->lng
      ];
      return $details;
    }


    function getDetails($address)
    {
      $apikey='googlesuppliedapikey';
      $locdetails=getLatLon($address);
      $latitude=$locdetails['lat'];
      $longitude=$locdetails['lng'];
      $curl=curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$latitude,$longitude&key=$apikey');
      curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      $json=curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);
      $json=json_decode($json);
      print_r($json);
    }


    $address='3342 Shawnee Avenue Avenue West Palm Beach, FL 33409';
    getDetails($address);
```

The latitude and longitude function works fine. My issue is within the `getDetails function`.

**My current response is the following**

```
stdClass Object
(
   [error_message] => The provided API key is invalid.
   [html_attributions] => Array
    (
    )

   [results] => Array
    (
    )

   [status] => REQUEST_DENIED
)
```

Not quite sure what the issue is. I literally just created this API key 5 minutes ago. **I also tried a prior key too which I created yesterday and it provided the same answer**

Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request URL is incorrect.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsRequests)

> **Place Details Requests**
>
> A Place Details request is an HTTP URL of the following form:
>
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/output?parameters
>   where output may be either of the following values:
>
> **json** (recommended) indicates output in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
>   xml indicates output as XML
>   Certain parameters are required to initiate a search request. As is standard in URLs, all parameters are separated using the ampersand (&) character. Below is a list of the parameters and their possible values.
>
> **key** (required) — Your application's API key. This key identifies your application for purposes of quota management and so that places added from your application are made immediately available to your app. Visit the Google Developers Console to create an API Project and obtain your key.
>   Either **placeid** or reference (you must supply one of these, but not both):
>   placeid — A textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place, returned from a Place Search. For more information about place IDs, see the place ID overview.
>   reference — A textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place, returned from a Place Search. Note: The reference is now deprecated in favor of placeid. See the deprecation notice on this page.